# After Lion upgrade I get "psql: could not connect to server: Permission Denied. Is editing /etc/paths the correct solution?

Tags: path, osx-lion

I've recently upgraded to OSX Lion and am having this annoying problem (bug?) with PostgreSQL.

```
psql: could not connect to server: Permission denied
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I've found a simple solution via changing the order of the paths file in `/etc/paths` and edit it from being:

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

to being:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

I've been told that I shouldn't be editing the actual `/etc/paths` file. Why is this so? What causes this bug? And what is the proper way of getting around it?

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you specified some basic information, like the version(s) of PostgreSQL installed, and how you installed each of them. The official EnterpriseDB installer? MacPorts? Postgres.app? Built in to some flavours of OS X? Some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Lion carries its own installation of PostgreSQL (installed in `/usr`), but you seem to have a manually installed (with Homebrew?) version installed in `/usr/local`.

Because of your `$PATH` setting, when you execute `psql` you start the OS X version (`/usr/bin/psql`), which isn't running by default. When you want to use your own version, you need to execute `/usr/local/bin/psql` instead.

Now for changing `/etc/paths`: there are better ways of picking which `psql` is started. Either you set your own `$PATH`:

```
# add this to $HOME/.bash_profile
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Or you could create an alias for `psql` which will point to the version in `/usr/local`:

```
# add this to $HOME/.bashrc
alias psql=/usr/local/bin/psql
```